# How to filter S3 files as input for Amazon EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run Amazon EMR Hadoop process that will process CloudFront logs in S3 bucket.  Since CloudFront generates a lot of logs in the same bucket, how do I filter the log files without generating extra bandwidth for S3 access?

Comment: Provide more information on where you want to filter. How often are you using amazon to download the log files? You may be able to use an API on CloudFront to filter log files.

Comment: Some kind of EMR process that run daily.  I would like to retrieve all logs for that day and used them as input for EMR.  Would you like to show me how to use CloudFront API as input for EMR Hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use `FileSystem.globStatus()` to quickly filter files from CloudFront logs bucket:

```
FileSystem fs = new Path("s3://logs").getFileSystem(conf);
for (FileStatus fileStatus: fs.globStatus("s3://logs/prefix-2015-11-01*")) {
   if (fileStatus.isFile()) {
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(myJob, fileStatus.getPath());
   }
}
```